# How to avoid multiple spaces in textfields?

Tags: flutter

Is there a way to stop the use of more than 1 space in a row in a textfield?.

Currently I am using this code to deal with a single space, but I don't want to end up with an infinitely long list of exceptions like the second image.

I do want to use spaces, just not at the start of my text or multiple spaces in a row.

[image]

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [trimRight()](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.4/dart-core/String/trimRight.html) to strip all leading whitespace from your value.

If you want to deal with trailing whitespace as well, you could just use [trim()](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.4/dart-core/String/trim.html)

Either way, both of these would catch all the exceptions you listed, whether there is an empty value, or a value with only whitespace.

I'm unsure if you are asking how to also replace multiple spaces inside the string with just single space? To do that you can use a regex, like this:

```dart
    value = value.trim();
    var singleSpaces = value.replaceAll(RegExp(r"\s+"), " ");
```